# How to discard older build while Fabric distribution?

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I have a problem with automated build distribution thru Fabric Beta with concurrent uploading. 
For example I starting upload of **first** build and 5 seconds after it I starting upload **second** one. But because Internet is a magic-unstable-box the **second** build have uploads *before* the **first** build. And it's treated as **first** build is *newer* then **second**. But it's not true.
So I want to discard older (**first**) build when I uploading newer one.
Or I want some other workaround for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. There is not an automated way within Fabric to stop the upload once it's started. You can manually remove versions via the app's settings page. From the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/app.html#remove-versions):

To remove, a specific version of your app, head to your app’s [settings](https://fabric.io/settings/apps). Select the app whose name you want to change and click on the “Versions” button. After that, select the toggle on any build or version you want to disable. Disabling a version prevents new crash reports from flowing in, hides it from the version filter, and prevents beta testers from installing that version.

Comment: Thank you Mike for quick reaction. Your solution is absolutely correct but impossible to implement on Continuos Integration server. So maybe any API exists for this purposes?

Comment: Anytime @EugeneNefedov. It's a good idea, but there isn't an API currently to remove or disable versions.